# How to refresh page when clicking on "go back one page" with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, webbrowser-control, browser-history

Well I know it's bad practice and I don't want to hold the user on my site to show him thousands of popup ads. It's just that I have some ajax loaded htm contents that are overwriting my index.html. So the url is the same but the page content is different. And when the user clicks "go back one page" in browser controls he will leave the site even if he doesn't want to. So to increase usability I want to refresh the page when he is doing that and an htm-content is loaded. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..
create a button with the id "back"
 Go back one page .

jquery..

```
$('#back').click(function(){
   document.location.href= "index.html";
});
```

Comment: Sorry but that's not what I meant. It can't be done with a simple click function. It's about browser controls and not buttons. These three things shall refresh the page: clicking on the left arrow in browser, the back arrow on the mouse and and back arrow (which normally deletes the last char)